# JS: Unexpected inheritance throught .push() method

Tags: javascript, object, inheritance

I am now develop some game engine that running in canvas. I have some basic, but now I want to add parents and childs... Everything running OK until I try add reference to child object to parent object. There is very short part of my problem:

```js
// Object that will be parent of obj1
var obj0 = {
  childs: [],
  someValue: 10,
  parent: null
}

// obj1 is defined from obj0 throught Object.assign(), so any change in
// obj1 will NOT reflect to obj0 (I added console.log() to show it)
var obj1 = Object.assign({}, obj0);
console.log("Expected result: false; Result: " + (obj0 == obj1));
obj1.someValue = 5;
console.log("Expected result: false; Result: " + (obj0.someValue == obj1.someValue));

// Now add obj0 as parent to obj1...
obj1.parent = obj0;

// ... and add obj1 as child to obj0 - I need to do this throught .parent
// (I can't directly do some change in obj1)
obj1.parent.childs.push(obj1);

// Everything seems be alright, but... If I look into obj1.childs...
console.log(obj1.childs)
// I see, that .push applied to all objects that are...
```

How you can see, `.push()` method is applied to all objects (in this case to both objects).

So my questions:
1. Why?
2. How I avoid it?

Thank you in advance...

Comment: The `Object.assign()` call results in both objects having a copy of the same `childs` array. It's a "shallow" copy.

Comment: @Pointy You are right, thanks.. But, have you any idea, how to avoid this?

Comment: Well you'd have to write your own code to copy one of your objects to another. In my experience wanting to do a "deep copy" is an indication of an architecture problem, and in the general case deep object copies are not always even possible.

Comment: @Pointy Yeah... I know that do a exactly copy of a object is very hard, but if I have there only empty array (and it will be empty every time, when I create a new object), can I do something as `obj1.childs = []` whenever I create a new one? There will be no reference, right?

Comment: `Object.assign` has nothing to do with inheritance. Did you mean `Object.create`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After `obj1 = Object.assign({}, obj0)`, both `obj0` and `obj1` reference the same `childs` array. So whatever mutation you bring to that array (e.g. by `push`), will be visible via both objects.

One way to get rid of such undesired effects is to create a constructor (a speciality of JavaScript), possibly even using the `class` notation:

```js
class MyClass {
    constructor(value) {
        this.childs = [];
        this.someValue = value;
        this.parent = null;
    }
}

// Object that will be parent of obj1
var obj0 = new MyClass(10);

var obj1 = new MyClass(5);
console.log("Expected result: false; Result: " + (obj0 == obj1));
console.log("Expected result: false; Result: " + (obj0.someValue == obj1.someValue));

// Now add obj0 as parent to obj1...
obj1.parent = obj0;
obj1.parent.childs.push(obj1);

// Everything is alright.
console.log(obj0.childs);
//  Nothing changed here:
console.log(obj1.childs);
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the comments, the problem is that `Object.assign` is a shallow copy, and ends up with both objects' `childs` property being the same array, so that when you `push` to one `childs` array, the other is updated as well (both `childs` arrays are one and the same).

Perhaps you'd like to use a class to define your objects:

```js
// Object that will be parent of obj1
class MyObj {
  constructor() {
    this.childs = [];
    this.someValue = 10;
    this.parent = null;
  }
}

var obj0 = new MyObj();
var obj1 = new MyObj();
console.log("Expected result: false; Result: " + (obj0 == obj1));
obj1.someValue = 5;
console.log("Expected result: false; Result: " + (obj0.someValue == obj1.someValue));

// Now add obj0 as parent to obj1...
obj1.parent = obj0;

// ... and add obj1 as child to obj0 - I need to do this throught .parent
// (I can't directly do some change in obj1)
obj1.parent.childs.push(obj1);

console.log("obj0's children:")
console.log(obj0.childs)
console.log("obj1's children:")
console.log(obj1.childs)
```